# Laravel only one request can be used in controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel's request class to validate my request. I've done that for my register post method like this.

```
public function RegisterPost(\App\Http\Requests\RegisterRequest $request)
    {
      $request->persist();
      return true;
    }
```

Now I'm trying to do the same for my `LoginPost` method. I've ran `php artisan make:request` and used it like this:

```
public function LoginPost(\App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest $request)
    {

    }
```

But for some reason I get this error:

```
Class App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest does not exist
```

I've also tried to do it like this:

```
use App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;
```

and then:

```
 public function LoginPost(LoginRequest $request)
        {

        }
```

But I get same result. This is not the first time this happens to me. But before I have ignored it, and just write validation logic in my controller

---

Edit:
Full stack trace as requested:

```
ReflectionException thrown with message "Class App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest does not exist"

Stacktrace:
#54 ReflectionException in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteSignatureParameters.php:25
#53 Illuminate\Routing\RouteSignatureParameters:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in [internal]:0
#52 ParseError in C:\code\laravel\app\Http\Requests\LoginRequest.php:39
#51 Composer\Autoload\includeFile in C:\code\laravel\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:322
#50 Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:loadClass in [internal]:0
#49 spl_autoload_call in [internal]:0
#48 ReflectionParameter:getClass in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteSignatureParameters.php:25
#47 Illuminate\Routing\RouteSignatureParameters:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in [internal]:0
#46 array_filter in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteSignatureParameters.php:26
#45 Illuminate\Routing\RouteSignatureParameters:fromAction in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:426
#44 Illuminate\Routing\Route:signatureParameters in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ImplicitRouteBinding.php:21
#43 Illuminate\Routing\ImplicitRouteBinding:resolveForRoute in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:701
#42 Illuminate\Routing\Router:substituteImplicitBindings in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings.php:39
#41 Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings:handle in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
#40 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
#39 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php:67
#38 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken:handle in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
#37 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
#36 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession.php:49
#35 Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession:handle in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
#34 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
#33 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php:63
#32 Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession:handle in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
#31 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
#30 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php:37
#29 Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse:handle in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
#28 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
#27 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php:59
#26 Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies:handle in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
#25 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
#24 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:102
#23 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:then in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:614
#22 Illuminate\Routing\Router:runRouteWithinStack in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:573
#21 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatchToRoute in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:551
#20 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatch in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:176
#19 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:30
#18 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\fideloper\proxy\src\TrustProxies.php:56
#17 Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies:handle in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
#16 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
#15 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php:30
#14 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest:handle in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
#13 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
#12 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php:30
#11 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest:handle in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
#10 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
#9 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php:27
#8 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize:handle in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
#7 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
#6 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:46
#5 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode:handle in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
#4 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
#3 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:102
#2 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:then in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:151
#1 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:sendRequestThroughRouter in C:\code\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:116
#0 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:handle in C:\code\laravel\public\index.php:55
```

Comment: Do you have `\App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest` created? Have you run `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: If you have generated request properly by following command

php artisan make:request LoginRequest
Double check that you have a file named LoginRequest.php under

app/Http/Requests

Comment: @aynber I do, created it with `php artisan make:request` and just tried `composer dump-autoload`, nothing changes

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi yeah its there, just next to RegisterRequest, now that one works just fine, but LoginRequest does not work. Created same way, imported same way

Comment: have you checked the class name in that LoginRequest ?

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi Yeah It's right

Comment: `namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class LoginRequest extends FormRequest`

Comment: Could you please give us the full stack trace of exception?

Comment: @MisaGH it's an ReflectionException happening here `…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteSignatureParameters.php:25`

Comment: Please update your question and post the full stack trace. not just a line of it

Comment: @MisaGH Done, question updated

Comment: I've tried it, it does work on `5.4.28` even without `dump-autoload`.

Comment: Provide your `App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest` code

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd It's literally just empty class generated by command, same as RegisterRequest (that works), exactly the same as I did not edit both classes

Comment: @Caranthir: That's why I want it to check that you given `namespace`. Can you please post it

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd Sure, ```<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class LoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [

         ];
    }
    

    
}
```